# Count SQL with aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I cannot count some records with some conditions.
I have this table for example

```
+-----+-----------------+-------+
| CCA |     NUMERO      | STATO |
+-----+-----------------+-------+
| 057 | 007030020004527 |     0 |
| 057 | 007030020004527 |     1 |
| 057 | 007030020004527 |     1 |
| 057 | 007030020004123 |     1 |
| 057 | 007030020004123 |     1 |
| 057 | 007030020001111 |     1 |
| 057 | 007030020001111 |     1 |
| 057 | 007030020001111 |     1 |
+-----+-----------------+-------+
```

The result that I expect for this example is

057  2

I want to count for each CCA the number of NUMERO when the COUNT(NUMERO) = SUM(STATO) but I cannot.
I tried something like this but the result is not correct (table name is sinistro)

```
SELECT cca, count(numero) AS totali, sum(stato) as gestiti 
FROM `sinistro`
GROUP BY sinistro.cca
HAVING (totali - gestiti) = 0
```

I can have the list of all the numero that have this condition but I cannot count them. I always obtain no rows.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
select t.cca, count(*) counter
from (
  select cca, numero
  from tablename
  group by cca, numero
  having count(*) = sum(stato) -- or having min(stato) = 1
) t
group by t.cca
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aRKdW9diLupHAy1roRYruS/0).

Or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select cca, count(distinct numero) counter
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from tablename
  where cca = t.cca and numero = t.numero and stato = 0
)
group by cca
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aRKdW9diLupHAy1roRYruS/2).
Results:

```
| cca | counter |
| --- | ------- |
| 57  | 2       |
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select cca
from sinistro
group by cca
having count(*) = sum(stato);
```

Comment: if i try ur sql no count aggregate row appears......i dont understand why :( if i write GROUP BY numero i obtain each rows but i cannot group and counting them......